# Error en la consola al usar value

Tags: javascript, html

estaba haciendo un ejercicio de cajero y cuando quise traer un número de la caja de texto del html a mi javascript, es decir obtener el valor del input y convertirlo a entero y extraer el valor no me funciona 'value' busqué en internet sobre el error y no pude encontrar algo al igual que estuve buscando un error de typo, espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano.[image: el error que me aparece en la consola es el siguiente]

```js
class Billete{
    constructor(v, c)
    {
        this.valor = v;
        this.cantidad = c;
    }
}

function entregarDinero()
{
    var t = document.getElementById("dinero");
    dinero = parseInt(t.value);   //en esta línea radica el problema
    for(var bi of caja)
    {
        if(dinero > 0)
        {
            div = Math.floor(dinero / bi.valor);
            if(div > bi.cantidad)
            {
                papeles = bi.cantidad;
            }
            else
            {
                papeles = div;
            }
            entregado.push( new Billete(bi.valor, papeles) );
            dinero = dinero - (bi.valor * papeles);
        }
    }
    if(dinero > 0)
    {
        alert("Dinero insuficiente");
    }
    console.log(entregado);
}

var caja = []
var entregado = []
caja.push( new Billete(50, 10) );
caja.push( new Billete(20, 30) );
caja.push( new Billete(10, 10) );
var dinero; 
var papeles = 0;
var div = 0;

var b = document.getElementById("retirar");
b.addEventListener("click", entregarDinero);
```

Comment: t es null porque no se encuentra un elemento con id "dinero"

Comment: Verifica que atributo tiene tu input, si es un id o un class y coloca las comillas al console.log("entregado");